# Can't i use same node in custom module. "<api>" in config.xml of module?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Core Magento have  `Mage::getModel("api/modulename");`

Now, I have a custom module which use `<api>` node in `config.xml` 
Like :

```
<models>
        <api>
              <class>Packagename_API_Model</class>
              <resourceModel>api_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </api>
        <api_mysql4>
                <class>Packagename_API_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <apilog>
                        <table>bh_api_log</table>
                    </apilog>
                </entities>
        </api_mysql4>
<models>
```

So now I am getting error in magento that

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object
>   in  code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Api\Grid\Role.php on line 48

As I have used same node tag which is `<api>` in my custom module.

Can't I use same node `<api>` ?
How can can use the same node tag in core and mycustom module so that both will work ?

Answer (score 0):

You indeed cannot use twice the same node for handles of the same type in Magento.

The best practice actually says that, for custom module, your handles should always use `packagename_modulename` as handles.

Let's say my module `config.xml` is actually in `app/code/local/B/Enoit/etc/config.xml`, the standard way of defining handles actually instruct me to write my `config.xml` that way :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <B_Enoit>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </B_Enoit>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <b_enoit>
                <class>B_Enoit_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>b_enoit_resource</resourceModel>
            </b_enoit>
            <b_enoit_resource>
                <class>B_Enoit_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <some_table>
                        <table>b_enoit_some_table</table>
                    </some_table>
                </entities>
            </b_enoit_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply will implement in your way add comment